# Remote Data Error while retrieving data from yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

Can you please help me with this code. Error is posted below the code.

```
    import pandas as pd 
    
    import pandas_datareader.data as web 
    
    import numpy as np 
    
    FB = web.YahooOptions('FB')
    
    for exp in FB.expiry_dates:
         print(exp.isoformat())
```

error:

> RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/FB
> Response Text:
> b'Forbidden'

Comment: Clicking on that link works for me.  It's possible you made too many requests during a short period and got temporarily blocked.

Answer (score 0):

from module release page:

> v0.6.0 (January 24, 2018)
>
> Highlights include:
>
> **Immediate deprecation of Yahoo!, Google Options** and Quotes and EDGAR. The end points behind these APIs have radically changed and the
> existing readers require complete rewrites. In the case of most Yahoo!
> data the endpoints have been removed. PDR would like to restore these
> features, and pull requests are welcome.

so I won't expect that works

to do what you want directly using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_json('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/FB')

for date in df['optionChain'][1][0]['expirationDates']:
    print(datetime.fromtimestamp(date).isoformat())
```

output:

```
>>>
2022-01-13T20:00:00
2022-01-20T20:00:00
2022-01-27T20:00:00
2022-02-03T20:00:00
2022-02-10T20:00:00
2022-02-17T20:00:00
2022-02-24T20:00:00
2022-03-03T20:00:00
2022-03-17T21:00:00
2022-04-13T21:00:00
2022-05-19T21:00:00
2022-06-16T21:00:00
2022-07-14T21:00:00
2022-09-15T21:00:00
2023-01-19T20:00:00
2023-03-16T21:00:00
2023-06-15T21:00:00
2024-01-18T20:00:00
2026-02-20T20:00:00

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Data_artist you’re welcome. Please accept upvote if it helped

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation to upvote any post. Will definitely come back and do it